# Which iterative linear solvers converge for positive semidefinite matrices?

Tags: linear-algebra, iterative-method, convergence, linear-solver

I want to know which of the classic linear solvers (e.g Gauss-Seidel, Jacobi, SOR) are guaranteed to converge for the problem $Ax=b$ where $A$ is positive **semi** definite and of course $b \in im(A)$

(Notice $A$ is semi definite and not definite)

Comment: Look up Conjugate Residual in Wikipedia.

Comment: Do you mean positive semi-definite matrices?

Comment: @meawoppl- yes, sorry, I will rephrase the question

Comment: What's the use of solving linear system with such matrix? If I'm not mistaken, if your positive semidefinite matrix is non-singular then it is simply positive definite.

Comment: CG and its derivatives (BiCG, CGNE etc.) will converge for positive definite matrices. During the computation of CG solutions, there is a $x^TAx$ term in the denominator which will cause Divide-by-zero in case that term is 0. Gauss-Seidel and Jacobi, as far as I know, need diagonally dominant matrices or Symmetric PD matrices.

Comment: @Nunoxic at least for CG, you are mistaken - CG is guaranteed to converge for Positive semidefinite matrices, that is, it will reach a solution $x$ s.t |Ax-b|=0 in case $b \in span(A) $

Comment: Are you sure? If you check out [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjugate_gradient_method#The_conjugate_gradient_method_as_an_iterative_method), the head does state that the matrix needs to be Positive Definite and also, if you see the link during the calculation of $\alpha$, the denominator would run to 0 (at some point of time) if the matrix wasn't strictly positive definite.

Comment: Yes, I am sure. I have to refresh my memory as for the actual proof, but per what you were saying - if the denominator in the calculation of $\alpha$ is zero, it means that $A P_k$ is zero, which means that all the "search directions" in which A is not singular have been exhausted, and the residual you are left with in not in the span of A (and thus this is the "optimal" solution). In the case that in fact $b \in span(A)$, this won't happen as the residual will reach zero just before the first time $AP_k=0$

Comment: @noam Do you have a citation for that proof?

Comment: Set $x_0=b$. Then $A^nb\in Im(A)$. CG will converge due to $x_n^\ast Ax_n> 0$ for all $0\ne x_n\in Im(A)$. In other words, you never leave $Im(A)$ for which $A$ is positive-definite.

Comment: @faleichik: reduced density matrices in quantum mechanics are positive semi-definite in very many cases.

Comment: Perhaps you could take a look at: http://www.cs.yale.edu/homes/spielman/PAPERS/icm10post.pdf

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The conjugate gradient algorithm works for semidefinite problems and produces the minimal norm solution.

Comment: thanks. Any idea about the "archaic" solvers, e.g SOR Gauss-Seidel etc.

Comment: They are hardly ever used anymore, and I don't know how these behave.

Comment: To clarify: CG most certainly does not work in vanilla form for semi-definite matrices; it may work in theory if B is in the image of A; but this is unlikely to end well in numerical-practice. The very similar krylov-based MINRES is a much better choice here. Also, these "archaic" solvers are widely used in multigrid-type solvers, to name one example.

Answer (score 1):

[Here is a proof](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/80793/is-gauss-seidel-guaranteed-to-converge-on-semi-positive-definite-matrices) that Gauss-Seidel fits your requirements, given that $b$ is in the image of $A$.

The same is very much not true of Jacobi; which is a shame since who wants to bother with Gauss-Seidel on modern computer hardware? If your problem can be split into diagonally-dominant blocks, you are in luck; you can apply Jacobi updates to those blocks in an incremental Gauss-Seidel fashion, and get the best of both for these type of semi-definite problems.